# How do I use change this code to be without any arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, filereader, filewriter

Hey StackOverflow community, I wanted to ask for some help with a school assignment I'm working on. To summarize the assignment, we basically have to create a text file, and write 2 things on one line. Then the program asks for a user input, and if that input matches the first things on any of the lines, print the second thing.

Example:

the line: "brb     be right back"
user input: "brb"
output: "be right back"

I have succeed in doing this, here is my code. You can run it to see what it does clearer.

```
// The "NetSpeak_raminAmiri" class.
import java.io.*;
public class NetSpeak_raminAmiri
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        sendLines ();
        readLines ();
    } // main method


    public static void sendLines ()
    {
        try
        {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("net.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (fw);

            pw.println ("brb\tbe right back");
            pw.println ("lol\tlaugh out loud");
            pw.println ("g2g\tgot got go");
            pw.println ("d8\tdate");
            pw.println ("h8\thate");
            pw.println ("luv\tlove");
            pw.println ("pos\tparents over shoulder");
            pw.println ("u\tyou");
            pw.println ("sup\twhat's up");
            pw.println ("yolo\tyou only live once");
            pw.println ("smh\tshake my head");
            pw.println ("lmao\tlaugh my ass off");
            pw.println ("ttyl\ttalk to you later");
            pw.println ("idc\ti don't care");
            pw.println ("idk\ti don't know");
            pw.println ("ily\ti love you");
            pw.println ("bae\tdanish word for poop");
            pw.println ("omg\toh my god");
            pw.println ("tmi\ttoo much information");
            pw.println ("tbh\tto be honest");
            pw.println ("jk\tjust kidding");
            pw.println ("ftw\tfor the win");
            pw.println ("np\tno problem");

            pw.close ();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
    } //sendLines method


    public static void readLines ()
    {
        try
        {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader ("speak.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
            String input;
            String line;

            System.out.println ("What net-speak would you like to translate?");
            input = In.getString ();

            while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null)
            {
                String translate[] = line.split ("\t");
                for (int i = 0 ; i < translate.length - 1 ; i++)
                {
                    if (input.equals (translate [i]))
                    {
                        System.out.println (translate [i + 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    } //readLines method
} // NetSpeak_raminAmiri class
```

All is well, until I noticed, in tiny letters: "note: do not use array"
And now I'm stuck.

I need help with figuring out how to do the same thing the code I made does, but without arrays. Is there a way?

Comment: Use a `Map<String, String>` such as a `HashMap<String, String>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use IndexOf and Substring

```
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            int p = line.IndexOf('\t');
            string key = line.Substring(0, p);
            if (input.equals(key))
            {
                System.out.println(line.Substring(p+1));
                break;
            }
        }
```